# How to do smart updates in mongodb using spring?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a smart and optimized way of updating data in mongo db? I do in below fashion now but wanted to do it with less calls to the database.

```
@Transactional
public void modifyParticipant(String id, String roomId, updates) {
    Conference conference = conferenceRepository.findParticipantsByRoomId(roomId);
    for(Participant participant : conference.getParticipants()){
        if(participant.getId().equals(id)){
            //modify the participant
            break;
        }
    }
    conference.updateTime();
    conferenceRepository.save(conference);
    }
```

I tried below way, but i was never successful because the query always gets the array of participants even though i was trying to get only one participant that matches with id. And the update fails because of array.

### Attempt

```
@Override
public void modifyParticipants(String id, String roomId, Map<String, String> map) {

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("_id").is(roomId), Criteria.where("participants").elemMatch(Criteria.where("_id").is(id))));
    Conference conference = operations.findOne(query, Conference.class);
    String temp;
    Update update = new Update();
    if((temp = map.get("firstName")) != null){
        update.push("participants.$.firstName",temp);
    }
    if((temp = map.get("lastName")) != null){
        update.push("participants.$.lastName", temp);
    }
    if((temp = map.get("avatarUrl")) != null){
        update.push("participants.$.avatarUrl",temp);
    }
    if((temp = map.get("state")) != null){
        update.push("participants.$.state", temp);
    }
    if((temp = map.get("avState")) != null){
        update.push("participants.$.avState", temp);
    }
    operations.updateFirst(query, update, Conference.class);
}
```

### Data Structure

```
{ 
    "_id" : "f9091ed9-c828-4b52-b1c3-44e42f719694", 
    .....,
    "participants" : [
        {
            "_id" : "6b49b373-1e61-4c98-a703-c1c2bc4da0e2", 
            "deviceId" : "7F55271D-946C-44B0-BFAC-461447021762", 
            "avatarUrl" : "", 
            "firstName" : "ddd", 
            "lastName" : "qwr", 
            "state" : "REMOVED", 
            "about" : "", 
            "avState" : "OFFLINE", 
            "version" : NumberInt(0), 
            "timeCreated" : ISODate("2015-11-09T00:36:41.585+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "48f32b8e-3c40-48c2-96fa-74e93c388cd1", 
            "deviceId" : "7F55271D-946C-44B0-BFAC-461447021762", 
            "avatarUrl" : "", 
            "firstName" : "wer", 
            "lastName" : "wrf", 
            "state" : "ONLINE", 
            "about" : "", 
            "avState" : "OFFLINE", 
            "version" : NumberInt(0), 
            "timeCreated" : ISODate("2015-11-09T00:37:24.574+0000")
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would ideally want to get the mongo shell equivalent of the following update operation which uses the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** operator with the **[`$ positional`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)** operator to identify an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. What this means is that any condition matching an element of an array on the query side of the update statement will only match the first array index found:

```
db.conference.update(
    {
        "_id": "f9091ed9-c828-4b52-b1c3-44e42f719694",
        "participants._id": "6b49b373-1e61-4c98-a703-c1c2bc4da0e2"
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "participants.$.firstName": "foo",
            "participants.$.lastName": "bar"
        }
    }
)
```

The Spring Data MongoDB example equivalent follows:

```
Query query = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(
    Criteria.where("_id").is("f9091ed9-c828-4b52-b1c3-44e42f719694"),
    Criteria.where("participants._id").is("6b49b373-1e61-4c98-a703-c1c2bc4da0e2"));

Update update = new Update();
update.set("participants.$.firstName", "foo");
update.set("participants.$.lastName", "bar");
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Conference.class);
```

Comment: if just do find i get the two participants but the update is working db.getCollection('session').find({ "$and" : [ {_id: "f9091ed9-c828-4b52-b1c3-44e42f719694"}, { "participants._id" : "6b49b373-1e61-4c98-a703-c1c2bc4da0e2"}]}). Was there any other way of just getting participant instead of all of them?

Comment: You can use [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to return just the participant array in the projection.